# How to fake arg constructor JustMock

Tags: c#, justmock

I don't know how to fake constructor has arg

```
Mock.SetupStatic(typeof(A), StaticConstructor.Mocked);
```

with Class A has Constructor arg s:

```
public A(string s)
{}
```

Please help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetupStatic is meant to be used with static constructors. In order to mock an instance constructor with arguments you can use Mock.Arrange like this:

```
        var expected = "StringArg";
        string arg = null;
        Mock.Arrange(() => new A(Arg.AnyString)).DoInstead<string>(x => arg = x);

        new A(expected);

        Assert.Equal(expected, arg);
```